# Expectation of next value conditioned on previous sample

Tags: bayesian, estimation, posterior, conditional-expectation

I've been studying for my estimation class, and I can't wrap my head around the lecturers notes. The question is about empirical bayes credibility models, but my confusion boils down to this:

Consider a sample $x_1,\dotsc,x_n$ where $X_i|\lambda\sim POI(\lambda)$, and $\lambda\sim GAM(2,2)$.

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left[ X_{n+1} | x_1,\dotsc,x_n \right] = \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathbb{E}\left[ X_{n+1}|\lambda \right] f(\lambda|x_1,\dotsc , x_n)  \, d\lambda = \int_{0}^{\infty} \, \lambda f(\lambda | x_1,\dotsc , x_n) d\lambda
\end{equation}

I understand that $\mathbb{E}\left[ X_{n+1} | \lambda \right] = \lambda$, since this is distributed according to Poisson, but why can we go from the left part to the middle part of the equations?

Edit: the lecturer made a mistake in the middle expression which I've now fixed. Why can we get to the middle expression from the first one?

Comment: You are correct, the bounds of integration in the middle expression should go from $0$ to $\infty$.   Typos happen!

Comment: This link to the Law of Total Expectation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation may help.